# In a Go slice, why does s[lo:hi] end at element hi-1?

Tags: go, slice

According to the [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/#33), in a Go slice `s`, the expression `s[lo:hi]` evaluates to a slice of the elements from `lo` through `hi-1`, inclusive:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    p := []int{0,  // slice position 0 
               10, // slice position 1
               20, // slice position 2
               30, // slice position 3
               40, // slice position 4
               50} // slice position 5

    fmt.Println(p[0:3]) // => [0 10 20]
}
```

In my code example above, "p[0:3]" would seem to intuitively "read" as: "the slice from position 0 to position 3", equating to [0, 10, 20, 30].  But of course, it actually equates to [0 10 20].

So my question is: what is the design rationale for the upper value evaluating to `hi-1` rather than simply `hi`?  It feels unintuitive, but there must be some reason for it that I'm missing, and I'm curious what that might be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ever seen another language that uses an inclusive range, where the length of the return is `hi-low+1`?

Comment: I presume you are asking this question as if to say: "that's the way that it's always done"? I'm afraid that does not help to answer my question.

Comment: no, I was actually curious if you ever seen it anywhere, leading you to the presumption that `len(s[low:hi]) == hi-low+1` in Go.

Comment: Sorry, what am I presuming? My question is taken directly from the Tour of Go.

Comment: It sounded like you were presuming what slice notation should be, contrary to what the specification and tour say. I just wanted to know if you had experience with another language with the semantics you expected, as I haven't seen any myself.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  Well, I suppose it was a presumption on my part in the sense that I was surprised by the behavior described in the tour.  It did not seem intuitive, but the answer below has helped me understand the reasons for that design.

Comment: There are quite a few languages with 1-based indexing convention. Scala, inconsistently, uses 0-based in some contexts and 1-based in others (notably tuples). The other language I've used that has slices like Go is Occam: it is also 0-based but uses the length instead of hi-1, i.e. [from:for] in their terminology, equivalent to [lo:hi-lo].

Comment: also see https://www.quora.com/Why-are-Python-ranges-half-open-exclusive-instead-of-closed-inclusive

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is completely a matter of convention, and there are certainly other ways to do it (for example, Matlab uses arrays whose first index is 1). The choice really comes down to what properties you want. As it turns out, using 0-indexed arrays where slicing is inclusive-exclusive (that is, a slice from `a` to `b` includes element `a` and excludes element `b`) has some really nice properties, and thus it's a very common choice. Here are a few advantages.

**Advantages of 0-indexed arrays and inclusive-exclusive slicing**

(Note that I'm using non-Go terminology, so I'll talk about arrays in the way that C or Java would talk about them. Arrays are what Go calls slices, and slices are sub-arrays (ie, "the slice from index 1 to index 4"))

- Pointer arithmetic works. If you're in a language like C, an array is really just a pointer to the first element in the array. Thus, if you use 0-indexed arrays, then you can say that the element at index `i` is just the element pointed at by the array pointer plus `i`. For example, if we have the array `[3 2 1]` with the address of the array being 10 (and assuming that each value takes up one byte of memory), then the address of the first element is 10 + 0 = 10, the address of the second is 10 + 1 = 11, and so on. In short, it makes the math simple.
- The length of a slice is also the place to slice it. That is, for an array `arr`, `arr[0:len(arr)]` is just `arr` itself. This comes in handy a lot in practice. For example, if I call `n, _ := r.Read(arr)` (where `n` is the number of bytes read into `arr`), then I can just do `arr[:n]` to get the slice of `arr` corresponding to the data that was actually written into `arr`.
- Indices don't overlap. This means that if I have `arr[0:i]`, `arr[i:j]`, `arr[j:k]`, `arr[k:len(arr)]`, these slices fully cover `arr` itself. You may not often find yourself partitioning an array into sub-slices like this, but it has a number of related advantages. For example, consider the following code to split an array based on non-consecutive integers:

  ```
    func consecutiveSlices(ints []int) [][]int {
        ret := make([][]int, 0)
        i, j := 0, 1
        for j < len(ints) {
            if ints[j] != ints[j-1] + 1 {
                ret = append(ret, ints[i:j])
                i = j
            }
        }
        ret = append(ret, ints[i:j])
    }
  ```

(This code obviously doesn't handle some edge cases well, but you get the idea.)

If we were to try to write the equivalent function using inclusive-inclusive slicing, it would be significantly more complicated.

If anyone can think of any more, please feel free to edit this answer and add them.

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Slice types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)
>
> [Slice expressions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)
>
> For a string, array, pointer to array, or slice a, the primary
>   expression
>
> ```
> a[low : high]
> ```
>
> constructs a substring or slice. The indices low and high select which
>   elements of operand a appear in the result. The result has indices
>   starting at `0` and length equal to `high - low`.
>
> For convenience, any of the indices may be omitted. A missing low
>   index defaults to zero; a missing high index defaults to the length of
>   the sliced operand
>
> For arrays or strings, the indices are in range if 0 <= low <= high <=
>   len(a), otherwise they are out of range. For slices, the upper index
>   bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length. A constant
>   index must be non-negative and representable by a value of type int;
>   for arrays or constant strings, constant indices must also be in
>   range. If both indices are constant, they must satisfy low <= high. If
>   the indices are out of range at run time, a run-time panic occurs.

For `q := p[m:n]`, `q` is a slice of `p` starting at index `m` for a length of `n-m` elements.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I had already consulted the spec and it does not provide the design *rationale* -- which is what I was looking for.