# What is the idea behind the notation of indices of Go slices?

Tags: go, indexing, slice

I can't seem to wrap my head around the notation of indices when working with Go slices.

Given a slice `s`.

```
 s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I now want to create a new slice `s2 = [2 3]`.

```
 s2 := s[1:3] // s2 = [2 3]
```

Now, what is the thought process that I should go through when accessing this value? Am I reading values starting from index `1` up to and including the third element of the slice? Or am I reading values from index `1` up to and excluding index `3`?

I am not starting at index `1` and going up to index `3` and neither am I starting at position `1` and going up to position `3` as both of these would result in `s2` having 3 elements.

What is the idea behind this notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant section from the spec: [Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions).

> For a string, array, pointer to array, or slice `a`, the primary expression
>
> ```
> a[low : high]
> ```
>
> constructs a substring or slice. The *indices* `low` and `high` select which elements of operand `a` appear in the result. **The result has indices starting at `0` and length equal to `high - low`**.

So `s2 := s[1:3]` creates a new slice with length `3 - 1 = 2`, so it will contain 2 elements: `s[1]` and `s[2]`.

When slicing a slice, `low` should be the index of the first element you want to include (**inclusive**), and `high` should be the index of the last element that will **not** be incuded (`high` is **exclusive**).

So if you want the result to include the elements `[2, 3]`, you need to provide slicing indices `1` and `3`:

```
s2 := s[1:3] // will be [2, 3]
```

What might be confusing is that the elements in your slice start with `1`, but the index starts with `0`.

For reasoning behind the inclusive-exclusive indices, see related question: [In a Go slice, why does s[lo:hi] end at element hi-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857582/in-a-go-slice-why-does-slohi-end-at-element-hi-1)

Comment: @SRC Yes, I see it, what is your question regarding to it? `s1` is a slice with one element only, `s[2]` is an index expression, denoting the 2nd (0 indexed) element which is `3`.

Comment: Maybe my example was poorly chosen. I am well aware of the difference between a single value access and creating a new slice. I actually meant to know how the idea behind the indices works as it seems the first value is an index while the second one is the position of the element starting with 1. I updated the question.

Comment: @sge See edited question. Also read the related question which details the logic behind it.

Comment: Allright. I guess I am confused since I work with matlab a lot and there s2[1:3] actually contains 3 values. Thanks for clarifying.