# Why panic does not occur?

Tags: go, slice

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    primes := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}

    for i, _ := range primes {

        s := i + 1
        fmt.Printf("%v => %v\n", s, primes[s:])

    }
}
```

and it produces the following values:

```
1 => [3 5 7 11 13]
2 => [5 7 11 13]
3 => [7 11 13]
4 => [11 13]
5 => [13]
6 => []
```

The question is, why panic does not occur here, it should be out of range. Why index 6 has an empty slice? 
Is slice like a list in functional programming?

Comment: There is no reason for a panic and it is okay to create an empty subslice, even at the end of a slice. "Is slice like a list in functional programming?" No.

Comment: Why it is empty? That is the point, that I do not understand.

Comment: There are 6 elements in prines and [6:6] (or [6:]) is a valid slice. It is empty though.

Comment: How many meters do you have to run if you start at 6m and are finished at 6m: 0 meters.

Comment: @Volker Wow nice explaination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spec: Slice expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

> For convenience, any of the indices may be omitted. A missing `low` index defaults to zero; a missing `high` index defaults to the length of the sliced operand.
>
> For arrays or strings, the indices are *in range* if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range. For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity `cap(a)` rather than the length.

The index goes from `0..len(primes)-1`, and so `s := i+1` will have `len(primes)` at max.

And the length is an allowed slice index. `primes[s:]` has a missing `high` index, so that defaults to `len(primes)`, and `primes[s:len(primes)]` is valid, but it will be an empty slice when `s == len(primes)`.

When slicing, the `low` index is inclusive, and `high` is exclusive, that's why the length is a valid index: `primes[:] = primes[0:len(primes)]`. For reasoning, see related questions: [What is the idea behind the notation of indices of Go slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318987/what-is-the-idea-behind-the-notation-of-indices-of-go-slices/40319047#40319047); and [In a Go slice, why does s[lo:hi] end at element hi-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857582/in-a-go-slice-why-does-slohi-end-at-element-hi-1/26858900#26858900)

Comment: Why with `primes[s:s]` do I get an empty slice?

Comment: @zero_coding I edited it to `primes[s:len(primes)]` is empty when `s == len(primes)`.

Comment: @zerocoding "When slicing, the low index is inclusive, and high is exclusive" meaning that if they are both the same index, that one and only ndex is excluded and so the result is a 0 element slice