# Why is the upper value of a slice's range one more than returned?

Tags: go, slice

Can someone please help me understand why the upper value of a slice's range in GO is one more than what is actually in the slice?
E.g.

```
var slice []byte = buffer[100:150]
```

This slice is 50 elements long and references elements 100 through 149 in the array.

I understand the math behind it; it slices elements from 100 with length (150-100); but I don't think it reads clearly and will cause lots of silly programming errors. Maybe if I understand their thinking behind the choice it won't urk me so much...  :-)
Thanks
Bryon

Comment: Look at the great answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857582/in-a-go-slice-why-does-slohi-end-at-element-hi-1

Comment: see: https://www.quora.com/Why-are-Python-ranges-half-open-exclusive-instead-of-closed-inclusive also